# How to get a series of time ranges with an increment in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to get a list of time series with increments of 15 minutes.

for example:

```
5:00 AM

5:15 AM

5:30 AM

....
...
.....

11:30 PM
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Groovy's [`TimeCategory`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/time/TimeCategory.html) you can do time manipulations (like adding a number of minutes to a date) quite easily. A runnable example:

```
import groovy.time.TimeCategory

def start = Date.parseToStringDate('Sun Feb 24 05:00:00 GMT 2013')

use (TimeCategory) {
    // An array of 10 Dates separated by a 15 minute time interval from 'start'.
    def timeSeries = (0..9).collect { start + (it * 15).minutes }

    // Formatted output.
    println timeSeries.collect { it.format('KK:mm a') }.join('\n')
}
```

Output (assuming system timezone is GMT):

```
05:00 AM
05:15 AM
05:30 AM
05:45 AM
06:00 AM
06:15 AM
06:30 AM
06:45 AM
07:00 AM
07:15 AM
```

**Update**

To get the time series between a `start` and `end` date, a functional kind of approach similar to what we did before would be:

```
import groovy.time.TimeCategory
import groovy.time.TimeDuration

def createTimeSeries(Date start, Date end, TimeDuration interval) {
    def step = interval.toMilliseconds() as int
    (start.time..end.time).step(step).collect { new Date(it) }
}

// Usage
use (TimeCategory) {
    def start = Date.parseToStringDate('Sun Feb 24 05:00:00 GMT 2013')
    def end = Date.parseToStringDate('Sun Feb 24 06:00:00 GMT 2013')
    def timeSeries = createTimeSeries(start, end, 15.minutes)

    assert timeSeries.size() == 5 // 5:00, 5:15, 5:30, 5:45 and 6:00
}
```

I *really* really wish the Range object and its [`step`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Range.html#step%28int%29) method would be more polymorphic, so `timeSeries = createTimeSeries(start, end, 15.minutes)` could be replaced by simply `timeSeries = (start..end).step(15.minutes)` (after all `start` and `end` areDates and therefore are Comparable between each other, and `15.minutes`, which is a TimeDuration, can be added to them); there'd be no need for the `createTimeSeries` function :)

However, *do not use this implementation*. For some reason the `Range#step` method is painfully slow on this case; it takes seconds to get the time series between a 1-day date difference on my laptop, even though they are just 97 elements :S

Here's a more imperative, but much faster, solution:

```
def createTimeSeries(Date start, Date end, TimeDuration interval) {
    def timeSeries = []
    while (start <= end) {
        timeSeries << start
        start += interval
    }
    timeSeries
}

// Usage is the same.
```

Comment: that works great! would be good to have `end` as a variable as well and then iterate over the duration between the `start` and `end`

Comment: @birdy Updated answer ;). It was fun to poke around with the Range objects and discover how slow they are in this case =D

Comment: For java 8's DateTime Api I came up with this version: `Collection<Instant> getDateRange(ZonedDateTime start, ZonedDateTime end, Duration step) {
        (start.toInstant().toEpochMilli()..end.toInstant().toEpochMilli()).step(step.toMillis() as int).collect {
            Instant.ofEpochMilli(it)
        }
    }` I also want to add that the return value is not a Range, but an ArrayList, that's why I explicitly declared it that way.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
Date start = ....
int periods = 26
int incrementMinutes = 15

return (1..periods).collect {
  new Date(start.time + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(it * incrementMinutes)
}
```